# How to compose ParamList for nested navigators in v5?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Say I have two navigators like this:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Bootstrap: undefined;
  Login: undefined;
  MainApp: undefined;
};

export type MainTabsParamList = {
  Explore: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
};

const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator<MainTabsParamList>();
const MainApp = () => (
  <MainTabs.Navigator >
    <MainTabs.Screen
      name="Explore"
      component={Explore}
    />
    <MainTabs.Screen
      name="Profile"
      component={Profile}
    />
  </MainTabs.Navigator>
);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Bootstrap" headerMode="none">
        <RootStack.Screen name="Bootstrap" component={Bootstrap} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="MainApp" component={MainApp} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Now if I want to navigate to `Profile` screen from `Bootstrap` screen. I have to write: (navigation prop properly annotated)

```
navigation.navigate('MainApp', {screen: 'Profile'})
```

But typescript gives error here. Saying `Type '{ screen: string; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'`. This is because typescript doesn't know `MainApp` has child screens. So I have to somehow compose the `ParamLists` so typescript knows about the child screens. How do I do that? Does `react-navigation` v5 support that?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there no solution out of the box, BUT have found this [thread (issue)](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6931). There we may found good [solution](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6931#issuecomment-643392469).

```
type NestedNavigatorParams<ParamList> = {
  [K in keyof ParamList]: undefined extends ParamList[K]
    ? { screen: K; params?: ParamList[K] }
    : { screen: K; params: ParamList[K] }
}[keyof ParamList]
```

It is very easy to use:

```
export type MainTabsParamList = {
  Explore: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
};

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Bootstrap: undefined;
  Login: undefined;
  MainApp: NestedNavigatorParams<MainTabsParamList>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying usage example, that was missing from the github issue 

Answer (score 1):

Update Feb 15, 2022: Looks like there is a solution out-of-the-box now :D

```js
import { NavigatorScreenParams } from '@react-navigation/native';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Bootstrap: undefined;
  Login: undefined;
  MainApp: NavigatorScreenParams<MainTabsParamList>;
};

export type MainTabsParamList = {
  Explore: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
};
```

See Documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-screens-and-params-in-nested-navigator